# clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: clojure

I am writing a function that, for any given string, replaces any digits within that String with the same number of '.' characters.

Examples:

AT2X -> AT..X

QW3G45 -> QW...G.........

T3Z1 -> T...Z.

I've written the following Clojure function but I am getting an error I don't quite understand:

java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq (in module: Unnamed Module) cannot be case to java.lang.Charsequence

I'm interpreting from the error that I need to force an evaluation of a lazy sequence back into a String (or CharSequence) but I can't figure out where to do so or if this is correct.

```
(defn dotify
    ;;Replaces digits with the same number of '.'s for use in traditional board formats
    [FEN]
    (let [values (doall (filter isDigit (seq FEN)))]
        (fn [values]
            (let [value (first values)]
                (str/replace FEN value (fn dots [number]
                                           (fn [s times]
                                               (if (> times 0)
                                                   (recur (str s ".") (dec times)))) "" (Character/digit number 10)) value))
        (recur (rest values))) values))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard `clojure.string/replace` function that may handle that case. Its last argument might be not just a string or a pattern but also a function that turns a found fragment into what you want.

Let's prepare such a function first:

```
(defn replacer [sum-str]
  (let [num (read-string num-str)]
    (apply str (repeat num \.))))
```

You may try it in this way:

```
user> (replacer "2")
..
user> (replacer "9")
.........
user> (replacer "22")
......................
user>
```

Now pass it into `replace` as follows:

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "a2b3c11" #"\d+" replacer)
a..b...c...........
```

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the names like `string` & `int`, using something more like:  `(let [num (read-string arg-str)] ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this using `reduce`:

```
(defn dotify [s]
  (->> s
       (reduce (fn [acc elem]
                 (if (Character/isDigit elem)
                   (let [dots (Integer/parseInt (str elem))]
                     (apply conj acc (repeat dots \.)))
                   (conj acc elem)))
               [])
       (apply str)))

(dotify "zx4g1z2h")
=> "zx....g.z..h"
```

And another version using `mapcat`:

```
(defn dotify-mapcat [s]
  (apply str
    (mapcat (fn [c]
              (if (Character/isDigit c)
                (repeat (Integer/parseInt (str c)) \.)
                [c]))
            s)))
```

There are some issues in your example:

1. Many of the internal forms are themselves functions, but it looks like you just want their bodies or implementations instead of wrapping them in functions.
2. It's hard to tell by the indentation/whitespace, but the entire function is just `recur`-ing, the `fn` above it is not being used or returned.
3. One of the arguments to `str/replace` is a function that returns a function.

It helps to break the problem down into smaller pieces. For one, you know you'll need to examine each character in a string and decide whether to just return it or expand it into a sequence of dots. So you can start with a function:

```
(defn expand-char [^Character c]
  (if (Character/isDigit c)
    (repeat (Integer/parseInt (str c)) \.)
    [c]))
```

Then use that function that operates on one character at a time in a *higher-order* function that operates on the entire string:

```
(apply str (mapcat expand-char s))
=> "zx....g.z..h"
```

Note this is also ~5x faster than the examples above because of the `^Character` type-hint in `expand-char` function.

You can do this with `str/replace` too:

```
(defn expand-char [s]
  (if (Character/isDigit ^Character (first s))
    (apply str (repeat (Integer/parseInt s) \.))
    s))
(str/replace "zx4g1z2h" #"." expand-char)
=> "zx....g.z..h"
```

Comment: Thank you! These are much more concise examples. Still getting the hang of when to use forms vs functions.